# Run ROR as a windows service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-services

I need to run my Ruby on rails application as a windows service in production environment . What is the ideal and reliable way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If a windows server is a must - I'd still go with Docker container for the app, because:

1. rails will run in a linux environment, you'll have less compatibility issues
2. you'll have Docker take care of process starting and monitoring, resource limiting
3. if you later choose to use other server - you can use the exact same container

Downside is a bit higher initial setup routine, but in the long run this should payoff.

Comment: Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: @SriKrishna if you can run development mode on that machine - nothing stops you from running production the same way, you can add a windows service entry to registry and have windows run that at startup, but I don't know how windows will monitor the process (restart it if needed) and how to make zero-downtime-deploy this way

Answer (score 0):

i was struggling with this problem for a long time and i resolved using nssm application, you can use it to generate windows services in easy way, i create a bat file making reference to ruby path and rails server command, something like that taking my personal project as reference

C:\Ruby27-x64\bin\ruby.exe c:/factura/factura/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production

first part in my ruby.exe location, by default is this, the second one is my app location plus bin/rails and the last one is to launch the server listennig in all local adresses in port 3000 in production mode, previously i ran rails assets:precompile and i changed some options in my production environment file and bundle install to install all dependencies

That option works perfectly in windows 10